# drupal 5 multiple blocks in a module

Tags: drupal

is it possible to declare more than 1 block in a module?

I tried to create a extra module in a block by changing the name to mymodulename_first_block and mymodulename_second_block but then i can't see them in th list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $delta variable for this: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/5
See example in bottom

Comment: i don't thing thats what i need, i need two different blocks because the have to be on a different location in my template.
It's just because they do almost the same job that i would like to put them in one module